# filter gridview based on dropdownlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

Im trying to do a exercise filter GridView based on selected value in DropDownList.
I have a list of names in dropdownlist and when i click in the name i want that information of persons appears in datagridview.
Im trying do this like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=eq;Password=*******;Unicode=True"); 
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("select * from teacher where idteacher={0} ", idteacher), con);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(table);
GridView1.DataSource = table;

}
```

but its not working, and "Datatable" object is not recognized buy c#.
Anyone can help me seeing what im doing wrong? 
Thanks!
Improve question   Permalink          Posted 7 min

Comment: is there an error involved here?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing where you initialize `idTeacher`.

However, you have to [`DataBind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) the `GridView` in ASP.NET after you have assigned the `DataSource`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();  // <-- this is missing in your code
```

You should use sql-parameters anyway, otherwise you are potentially open for sql-injection and you should use the `using` statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed (even on error):

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection("ConnectionString"))
using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from teacher where idteacher=@idTeacher", con))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idteacher", idTeacher);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(table); // opening or closing connection not needed, done by Fill
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks..i forgot databind(). but datatable object still not recognized for c#...do you know why can be?

Comment: Have you added the using? `using System.Data;` or using fully qualified name: `var table = new System.Data.DataTable();`

Comment: i was just using "using.system.data.oracleclient". Now i put that and it is recognized. but now i have a error in connection string: "An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider = SQLOLEDB;'." but i paste the connection string so i think its correct :S

Comment: Have a look here for valid oracle conncetion strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-msdaora If you cannot fix it you might want to ask another question with the exact error message since this questions is not realated to the connection-string issue.

Comment: thanks, excelent site! but you know why i have this error now in dataadapter.fill(table)?; sorry to be boring but it is really important understand this exercise!

Comment: I'm not sure but have you provided the `provider`? For example: `new OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source= ...`

Comment: in this line: dataadapter.fill(table)

Comment: @user2469122: Maybe oracle (or the oledbdataadapter) doesn't support named parameters. So try `?` instead. `new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from teacher where idteacher=?)` and `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", idTeacher);`. Remember to accept the answer if it solved the original problem. Good night.

Comment: now i have this code working, but i want to show just teacher with code 5, do you know how i can associate my sql command with dropdownlist selected value?

Comment: I´m new ate this excelent forum, there is something i can do vote or something for your excelent help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Provide Provider Name in Your connection String.